# POST parameters are truncated

Tags: angular, ripple, openiddict

Having a strange issue with my request from an angular 2 application to an asp.net core 1.0 web api server. The server is using OpenIddict.

Here's the request:

[image: Request Header Information]

In the api endpoint /connect/token
`var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIdConnectRequest();`

[image: Request parameter]

The request variable has a few parameters, one being the Resource parameter, which contains a URI. The URI is being truncated.

The result is that the OpenIddict library is unable to correctly match the resource, therefore is not able to authenticate, since the provided URI does not match the resource URI.

Comment: I've recently had some help from Kevin Chalet with OpenIddict, noticed the X-Powered By: Express , which points to the ripple emulator. Specifically, the Proxy Settings was set to "local", having switched to "Disabled" removed the issue, which posted incorrect URI to the api endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

There is an an open, unresolved bug that is associated with the `local` proxy and CORS. The suggestion is to set your ripple proxy setting to `remote` or `disabled` instead of `local`.

Here is the issue: [Ripple cuts json sent by POST](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/RIPPLE-49).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll work with Ripple more closely. Thanks!